# How to return List not null in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list like `List<String?> list1 = ['a', 'b', null, 'c']`

How do i get it `List<String> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

In Swift I can use compactMap and in Flutter is there any way like compactMap?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like :

```
List<String> list2 = list1.nonNulls.toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this short way:

```
final List<String> list2 = list1.whereType<String>().toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an equivalent method in Flutter called `whereType()` which can be used to filter out null values from a list.

```dart
List<String?> list1 = ['a', 'b', null, 'c'];
List<String> list2 = list1.whereType<String>().toList();
print(list2); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String?> list1 = ['a', 'b', null, 'c']
list1.removeWhere((value) => value == null);
```

or

```
List<String?> list1  = ['a', 'b', null, 'c'];
List<String> list2  = list1.whereType<String>().toList();
```